# Change RZ11 Profile parameters programmatically

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I was asked by the IT Department to write an ABAP program that switches  the profile parameter `login/server_logon_restriction` from 0 to 1 and back automatically triggered (time etc) on all of our SAP servers.

I am not very familiar in the SAP environment yet and until now I managed to get the wanted parameter by using:

```
RSAN_SYSTEM_PARAMETERS_GET
```

and

```
RSAN_SYSTEM_PARAMETERS_READ
```

But I cannot find anything to change and save them dynamically. Is this even possible?

Cheers, Nils

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`login/server_logon_restriction` parameter dynamic so you can change it via `cl_spfl_profile_parameter=>change_value` class method.

You can configure background job for automatically trigger it in t-code SM36.

The method don't save the given value to profile file, so the parameter turn back profile value after system restart.

Current logged-in users can continue to use system. May be you can want to inform them with `TH_POPUP` function then kick from the system.

Comment: Note that it works only for one application server at a time, you need to call it for each application server of your SAP system. The list of application servers may be obtained by calling the function module `TH_SERVER_LIST`.

Answer (score 0):

Example of code using `cl_spfl_profile_parameter=>change_value`, which works well on ABAP 7.40 SP 23 (NB: `sapgui/user_scripting` is a **dynamic** parameter i.e., it can be changed at runtime).

Note that it works along with the function module `TH_SERVER_LIST`, in case the SAP instance runs with several application servers (for load distribution):

```
REPORT z_activate_sap_gui_scripting.

TYPES tt_server TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF msxxlist WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA(lt_server) = VALUE tt_server( ).
CALL FUNCTION 'TH_SERVER_LIST' TABLES list = lt_server.

LOOP AT lt_server REFERENCE INTO DATA(ls_server).
  cl_spfl_profile_parameter=>change_value(
    EXPORTING
      name        = 'sapgui/user_scripting'
      value       = 'TRUE'
      server_name = CONV #( ls_server->name )
    IMPORTING
      msg         = DATA(msg)
    RECEIVING
      rc          = DATA(rc) ).
  WRITE : / ls_server->name, rc, msg.
ENDLOOP.
```

The effect of dynamic switching can be seen via the transaction code `RZ11`:
[image: RZ11 profile parameter value of sapgui/user_scripting]

NB: not related to the topic, only specific to `sapgui/user_scripting`, the effect can be also seen by logoff and logon again > SAP GUI options > Script Recording and Playback is activated:

[image]